# Jquery to display multiple input fields

Tags: jquery, html

I'm a rookie programmer trying to achieve something that would function this way.
I have one text box displaying with a button which says add new text box. Onclick of a button named add new field, jquery shows a new text field. So if a user clicks it they can add more than one field at a time.
I'll appreciate if i can get help with this.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: Nice story... but what's the question with it?

Comment: [http://api.jquery.com/appendto/](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rough example

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    var num = parseInt($('#num').val(), 10);
    if (!isNaN(num)) {
          var $div = $('#div');
        for(var i=0;i< num;i++) {
             $div.append('<input type="text" />')   ;
        }
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/yzsBq/)**

Comment: Thanks, i really do appreciate. However how do i remove an input box i dont need.

Answer (score 0):

within your [**jquery you can try this**](http://jsfiddle.net/R8YYX/)

```
$('.buttonClass').click(function(){
     $("<input placeholder='this is a new textbox'/>").appendTo('body');
});
```

two things to note:
you will definitely want to set a int variable that will increment each time you make a new textbox and assign them each a unique name / id so you can grab then data from them easier

and you will want to append these elements to your form rather than to the 'body' of the document

Comment: Thanks. I really do appreciate